# Grandchild component not changing grandparent state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is a button 2 layers deep in a NavigatorIOS that when triggered, should change the TabBarIOS selected TabBarIOS Item.

The components are structured as follows:
--FooterTabs
------NavigatorIOS:List -> ListItem

I am attempting to do the above by having a function inside FooterTabs that changes the state, and having TabBar.Items whose prop 'selected' becomes true when the state's 'selectedTab'=== different strings.

Like so:

```
_changeToAlarms(){
    console.log('Hello from Footer Tabs');
    this.setState({
      selectedTab: 'Alarms'
    });
  }

render(){
  return(
    <Icon.TabBarItemIOS title={'Alarms'}
              iconName='ios-clock'
              selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Alarms'}
              onPress={()=> {
                this.setState({
                  selectedTab: 'Alarms'
                });
              }}>
              <ComingSoon/>
            </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>

<Icon.TabBarItemIOS title={'Schedules'}
                  iconName='ios-moon'
                  selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Schedules'}
                  onPress={()=> {
                    this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'Schedules'
                    });
                  }}>
                </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
  );
}
```

*Icon.TabBatItem acts exactly like TabBarIOS.Item.

onPress works, but to be able to change the tab in a similar fashion (by modifying the component's state) I passed _changeToAlarms() as a prop to 'SleepSchedules'.

```
<Icon.TabBarItemIOS ...
                  >
                  <NavigatorIOS
                    initialRoute={{
                      component: SleepSchedules ,
                      title: ' ',
                      passProps: {changeToAlarms: ()=> this._changeToAlarms()}
                    }}
                    style={{flex: 1}}
                    />
                </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
```

And from **SleepSchedules**, I am navigating to the next component and passing the previous'changeToAlarms' as a prop.

```
_handlePress(selectedSchedule){
    this.setState({selectedSchedule});

    this._navScheduleItem(selectedSchedule)
  }

   _navScheduleItem(scheduleName){

     this.props.navigator.push({
         title: `${scheduleName} Sleep`,
         component: ScheduleItem,
         passProps: {scheduleName}, changeToAlarms: ()=> this.props.changeToAlarms
     })
   }

render(){
   return(
      ...
      onPress={()=> this._handlePress('Monophasic')}>
   );
}
```

And in **ScheduleItem** I am attempting to call the prop 'changeToAlarm' that was passed, which should be the one from **Footer Tabs**.

```
_handleTouch(){
  console.log('Hello from Schedule Item');
  this.props.changeToAlarms;
}

render(){
   return(
      ...
      onPress={()=> this._handleTouch()}
   );
}
```

The console logs 'Hello from ScheduleItem' every time I press it, but doesn't log 'Hello from FooterTabs' nor does it change the tab.

Does anyone spot an error?

I am a beginner, so thank you much for your help! :)

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct way to approach the problem, but this is how I conceptualized it. If there are any errors in my approach then feel free to comment on the correct way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need a () after this.props.changeToAlarms. this.props.changeToAlarms()

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a better approach but without seeing more code its hard to get the full picture of whats going on.  On thing that did catch my eye was in your _handlePress function.   You called setState and then another function.

According to [ReactDocs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html):

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.

This might be causing an issue for you, again without more code its hard to tell.  You can try using the [overload method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for setState that takes a function as the second arg.

> setState(nextState, callback) 
>   Performs a shallow merge of nextState into current state. This is the primary > method you use to trigger UI updates from event handlers and server request > > callbacks.
>
> The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to
>   update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object
>   containing keys to update.

This ensures your setstate completes before your next function is executed.

```
_handlePress(selectedSchedule){
    this.setState({selectedSchedule}, () => 
    {
        this._navScheduleItem(selectedSchedule);
    });
  }
```